# error when adding string value to array index

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, indexing

```java
public class aa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 521;
        String temp1 = "" + number;
        int result = 0;
        int[] temp2 = new int[temp1.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<temp1.length(); i++){
            int len = temp1.length();
            temp2[i] = temp1.charAt(len-i-1);
            System.out.println(temp2[i]);
            System.out.println(temp1.charAt(len-i-1));
        }

    }
    
}
```

This program should make 521 to 125 (reverse). But when I run this program, the result is

```
49
1
50
2
53
5
```

I think that string value is right, but when I add that string value to array, it goes wrong way. Can some one tell me what is wrong?

Comment: For starters, `println` prints a newline at the end of it output, so there's no way your output will be on one line only if you use that. Second, `temp2` is an array of `int`s, you can't expect `println` to know you actually wanted `char`s if you ask it to print numbers.

Comment: You can easily find 1000s of articles on [how to reverse a number in java](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+reverse+a+number+in+java).

Comment: @AlexRudenko That doesn't really explain what the problem is with *this* approach. That question is about alternative approaches. The one OP is using, while not optimal, would work once they fix the type of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying in the comments, `temp2` is the wrong type. You declared it as an array of `int`s, so `println`, of course, is treating it as an array of numbers, not of printable characters.

Just change `temp2`'s type to `char[]`:

```
public class aa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 521;
        String temp1 = "" + number;
        int result = 0;
        char[] temp2 = new char[temp1.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<temp1.length(); i++){
            int len = temp1.length();
            temp2[i] = temp1.charAt(len-i-1);
            System.out.println(temp2[i]);
            System.out.println(temp1.charAt(len-i-1));
        }

        // print the whole reversed number on one line
        for(char c : temp2) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    
}
```

Output

```
1
1
2
2
5
5
125
```

Of course this is not the optimal solution, just a way to fix the code you wrote so that it works. See [Alex Rudenko's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66840095/error-when-adding-string-value-to-array-index#comment118150652_66840095) for a link with better solutions to the problem of reversing the digits of a number.

Answer (score 0):

As `temp2` is an array of `int` values, the following assignment needs to be fixed:

```java
temp2[i] = temp1.charAt(len-i-1);
```

because it assign an ASCII value of `char`.

This can be done by subtracting a `0` or by using `Character::getNumericValue`

```
temp2[i] = temp1.charAt(len-i-1) - '0';
// or
temp2[i] = Character.getNumericValue(temp1.charAt(len-i-1));
```

---

A non-negative integer number may be reversed without using any String conversion:

1. The "length" of `temp2` array is defined by `Math.log10`
2. Each digit is calculated with modulo operator `%` and dividing the input while it is greater than 0

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 521;

    int len = number < 2 ? 1 : (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(number));
    
    int[] temp2 = new int[len];
    
    for (int i = 0, n = number; n > 0; n /= 10, i++) {
        
        temp2[i] = n % 10;
        
        System.out.println(temp2[i]);
    }
    for (int i : temp2) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
1
2
5
125
```

Answer (score -1):

You question is not very clear about if you are asking for opinion. But a query that **"when I add that string value to array, it goes wrong way."**

So , String is a reference type, while your array is of int type. You need to parse the value from String to int

**`Integer.parseInt(String)`**

Comment: `String temp1 = "" + number;` works. That's not optimal but it surely is not the problem with this code

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think question was related to String value to array and that is what was explain. Since array was of int type. I have not referred to int assigned to String.